# Get the latest updated sub-directory

Tags: .net, linq, algorithm, file-io

Am trying to find the latest sub-directory from a parent director.

```
public static DirectoryInfo GetLatestSubDirectory(string parentDirPath)
```

As of now the implementation is uses the **bubble sort** algorithm to find the latest by comparing the creation time.

```
 if (subDirInfo.CreationTimeUtc > latestSubDirInfo.CreationTimeUtc)
```

Am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this?
LINQ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return new DirectoryInfo(parentDirPath)
           .GetDirectories()
           .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTimeUtc)
           .First()
```

Answer (score 0):

By latest I guess you mean the newest. I'm wondering why for selecting the minimum / maximum item from a collection people tend to use sorting or LINQ.

```
DirectoryInfo newest = null;
foreach(string subdirName in Directory.GetDirectory(path))
{
    DirectoryInfo subdirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subdirName);
    if (newest == null || subdirInfo.CreationTimeUct > newest.CreationTimeUct) 
        newest = subdirInfo;
}
```